# Will the Nest API support reading the state of the system?

Tags: nest-api

The API doesn't give any information on the state of the HVAC system, i.e. heating, cooling, fan. Will this be added in the future?

Comment: Do they not have a support site of their own? Asking *us* what *they* have in mind doesn't make much sense; we can't read their minds.

Comment: They tell us to come here to ask questions. I assumed they had their people answering the questions. Wishful thinking, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine the cooling/heating mode using the "hvac_mode" property (https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api#hvac_mode), and "fan_timer_active" to check if the fan timer is running. You can also query the target properties, starting with "target_temperature_f" (https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api#target_temperature_f)

Comment: As Jason mentioned below, this is not the state of the system. It's merely telling you what mode it is in.

Answer (score 2):

No, HVAC mode isn't the same as HVAC state. My system could be in cooling mode but not actively making a call for cooling. If you know the swing value you can guess based on the difference between set point and actual temp but that really isn't reliable.

Presumably this might be to prevent replication of existing Nest functionality?

Comment: I think they want to be the only source of a home's heating/cooling profile. Not having this in the API takes away a lot of the cool stuff you can do.

Comment: What do you mean by "swing value"? Is the goal here to determine if the AC compressor/furnace is actually running, and the house isn't cooling/heating by other means? If Nest won't give that up, then perhaps you can (eventually) measure by other means, using a smart meters and what not. I think it's futile for Nest to keep that hidden, since it's relatively simple to reverse engineer.

Comment: This is terrible news!  My company develops demand control systems which needs to be able to read and write the HVAC state... the exclusion of this essentially means we can't use NESTs :-(  I am currently getting HVAC status via their old unofficial API which I assume will disappear one day.