# Nest API - how to get current state?

Tags: nest-api

Does the Nest API allow read access of the thermostat current state(S) (is heating/is cooling/is fan on)?

I can't see it in the API Reference, or the actual JSON, but it seems strange that the Nest Developer Chrome Extension allows the state to be changed if it cannot be accessed by the API.

Comment: There is already a discussion of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396384/will-the-nest-api-support-reading-the-state-of-the-system

Comment: Thanks - I missed that one